# Accepting incoming call twilio(Obtain the name to client who made the call)

Tags: android, twilio

I am developing a simple voice chat android application using twilio. I am being able to make outgoing  calls and also accept incoming calls using client names. This is my twilio voice url php script :

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$client= $_REQUEST["userName"];

 ?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="<?php echo $client ?>">
        <Client><?php echo $number;?></Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

What I need to do is I need to display the name of the calling client to the user receiving the incoming call but I am unable to figure out how to obtain the name of calling client. I even tried doing this,

```
 @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Device device = intent.getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Connection incoming = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);
            incoming.setConnectionListener(this);
                    String clientName =  Connection.getParameters().get(incoming.IncomingParameterFromKey);

            Log.i(TAG, "Call from : " + clientName);
        }
```

but I got following logcat output:

```
12-13 16:17:25.531: E/Voice chat sample app log(16157): Call from : 873797
```

I am getting a number `873797` instead of client name.

There might be some way to obtain the name of the client. I also went through twilio documentation with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just go to this link

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming

> ```
>    1. Click on your twilio number. 
>    2. Enter into the Configure Tab
>   3. Go into Voice . Check the Url in Configure with:
>   4. Over there you have a drop down of Caller Name Lookup that is set to disabled. Enable it .
> ```

Hope this works for you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with this,

Hope it helps

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent != null) {
        /*
         * Determine if the receiving Intent has an extra for the incoming connection. If so,
         * remove it from the Intent to prevent handling it again next time the Activity is resumed
         */
        Device device = intent.getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        Connection incomingConnection = intent.getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);
        if (incomingConnection == null && device == null) {
            return;
        }
        intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);

        pendingConnection = incomingConnection;
        pendingConnection.setConnectionListener(this);

        String incomingRecipientCallNumber = pendingConnection.getParameters().get(incomingConnection.IncomingParameterFromKey);

        showRecipientNumber.setText(incomingRecipientCallNumber);

        showIncomingDialog();
    }
}
```